# Use Reticulate to call file function

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I want to use `reticulate` to reproduce this Python code in R:

```
file("my.png").read()
```

In R I have tried this:

```
library(reticulate)
funcs <- import_builtins()
funcs$file("my.png").read()
```

This errors saying that `funcs$file` is not a function.

It isn't clear to me how I would pass a filepath to the Python `file` function.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple (and "raw") example for reading a file using `reticulate` and the Python built-in functions.
The content of `myfile.txt` is:

```
ds y
"2017-05-23 08:07:00" 21.16641
"2017-05-23 08:07:10" 16.79345
"2017-05-23 08:07:20" 16.40846
"2017-05-23 08:07:30" 16.24653
"2017-05-23 08:07:40" 16.14694
"2017-05-23 08:07:50" 15.89552
```

and the code to read the file is:

```
library(reticulate)
funcs <- import_builtins()

fl <- funcs$open("myfile.txt", "r")
txt <- fl$readlines()    
fl$close()

cat(txt)

#  ds y
#  "2017-05-23 08:07:00" 21.16641
#  "2017-05-23 08:07:10" 16.79345
#  "2017-05-23 08:07:20" 16.40846
#  "2017-05-23 08:07:30" 16.24653
#  "2017-05-23 08:07:40" 16.14694
#  "2017-05-23 08:07:50" 15.89552
```

An alternative solution using the built-in `file` function is:

```
fl <- funcs$open("myfile.txt", "r")
txt <- funcs$file$readlines(fl)  
fl$close()
```